# Ext Js 5.0.1 Dynamic Localization in sencha architect

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs5

How to implement dynamic localization in sencha architect Extjs 5.0. There is no working examples. I found multi-lang js for 5.0 but no idea how to start in sencha architect. Can some once help me?
http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/locale/multi-lang.html
sencha localization extjs 5.0

Comment: Are you asking about localizing your own application or just Ext widgets?

Comment: Am localizing my application!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In this [article](http://blogs.walkingtree.in/2011/11/26/localizing-sencha-touch-application/) you can see how to localize our Sencha Touch based application. There are two aspects to this. One, you can see how to localize the Sencha Touch framework related messages, formats, etc. Second, you will see how to localize our application specific messages and formats.

Comment: 1.First thing is i need to implement in sencha architect with extjs 5.0 but here the article is for sencha touch. The problem is, sencha architect will  override code which is written out side the architect. 
2. As mentioned in the article title: Messages.PERSONAL_INFO.  PERSONAL_INFO in messages object can be updated in sencha touch. But in sencha architect title value can only updated in config which is placed on right side in architect. This is replacing the content in quote. example  title: 'Messages.PERSONAL_INFO'.  So its considering as a string.

Comment: Almost i done with http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/locale/multi-lang.html in architect. I will update the steps. How ever thanks!!!!!!